# How to grab addresses (string) inputted into PlaceAutoCompleteFragment that is not found in the API's database?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using Google's PlaceAutoCompleteFragment but in the case that there are "No Results Found" in the API's database, I would like to grab the inputted text and close the PlaceAutoCompleteFragment widget.  That way if the user just so happens to input an address that is not in Google's database, I can take the inputted text and populate an EditText box with it and move forward with that as the user's address. [Screenshot of "No Results Found" PlaceAutoCompleteFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu31A.png)

```
mStreetAutocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.d(TAG, "PLace selected");
            placeSelected = true;
            mLatLng = place.getLatLng();
            mLatitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            mLongitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.d(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

Neither onPlaceSelected nor onError gets called if I enter an address that is not in the API's database.  Not sure how to get around this and account for these not found addresses?

Comment: This could get very involved here.  You may have to do a lot of custom work to get the behavior you want.  The best solution might be to show the exact address the user entered as a default option, perhaps highlighted in some way to show that it is a no-match option.  Start by reading here: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity

Comment: You almost certainly _won't_ be able to use the default widget.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Appreciate the help!